# URL link to amazon page inside game

Tags: app-store-connect

Is it against any Apple developer rules to put a URL in a game somewhere, which links to a page on Amazon? and/or a link to a bloggers website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

The rules are not always crystal clear, so it really depends on what "somewhere" ends up being in practice. It very much matters what that URL is during review but also if users complain to Apple that you are steering commerce to sites against their will, you might run into issues.

I would say - follow the money. If this is a sustained effort to monetize an app, you would likely run afoul of several of the items in Apple's published "Living Document" for app review guidelines:

- https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Specifically:

> Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the App, such as a "buy" button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected
>
> Apps offering subscriptions must do so using IAP

There will be more restrictions on links if your app is sold into a Kids rating or category. As long as the links enhance the user experience, are not intended (or could possibly be construed) as bypassing subscription and revenue functions that could be accomplished with IAP, you should be clear with general links if they are not the sole purpose of your app.

Comment: A follow on question. I've been asked to add a link in an app to a companion book offered through Amazon. Would that be considered ok? Thanks